# Hangman Game Correct Words Function

Tags: python

```
import random

HANGMANPICS = ['''

+------+
|      |
|      |
       |
       |
       |
       |
       |
       |
       |
       |
==============''', '''

+      +
|      |
|      |
O      |
       |
       |
       |
       |
       |
       |
       |
==============''', '''
+------+
|      |
|      |
|      |
O      |
|      |
|      |
|      |
       |
       |
==============''']

words = 'ant baboon badger bat bear beaver beetle bird camel cat clam cobra cougar coyote crab crane crow deer dog donkey duck eagle ferret fish fox frog goat goose hawk iguana jackal koala leech lemur lion lizard llama mite monkey moose moth mouse mule newt otter owl oyster panda parrot pigeon python quail rabbit ram rat raven rhino salmon seal shark sheep skunk sloth slug snail snake spider squid stork swan tick tiger toad trout turkey turtle wasp weasel whale wolf wombat worm zebra'.split()

# This function returns a random string from the list of strings.
def getRandomWord(wordList): 
    wordIndex = random.randint(0, len(wordList) - 1)
return wordList[wordIndex]

def displayBoard(HANGMANPICS, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord):
    print HANGMANPICS[len(missedLetters)]
print

print 'Missed Letters:',
for letter in missedLetters:
    print letter,
print

blanks = '_' * len(secretWord)

for i in range(len(secretWord)):
  if secretWord[i] in correctLetters:
    blanks = blanks[:i] + secretWord[i] + blanks[i+1:]

for letter in blanks:
    print letter,
print

def getGuess(alreadyGuessed):
    while True:
        print 'Guess a letter.'
        guess = raw_input()
        guess = guess.lower()
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print 'Please enter a single letter.'
        elif guess in alreadyGuessed:
            print 'You have already guessed that letter. Choose again.'
        elif guess not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
            print 'Please enter a LETTER.'
        else:
            return guess

def playAgain():
    print 'Do you want to play again? (yes or no)'
    return raw_input().lower().startswith('y')


print 'HANGMAN'
missedLetters = ''
correctLetters = ''
secretWord = getRandomWord(words)
gameIsDone = False

while True:
    displayBoard(HANGMANPICS, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord)

    guess = getGuess(missedLetters + correctLetters)

if guess in secretWord:
    correctLetters = correctLetters + guess

    foundAllLetters = True
    for i in range(len(secretWord)):
        if secretWord[i] not in correctLetters:
            foundAllLetters = False
            break
    if foundAllLetters:
        print 'Yes! The secret word is "' + secretWord + '"! You have won!'
        gameIsDone = True
else:
  missedLetters = missedLetters + guess

  if len(missedLetters) == len(HANGMANPICS) - 1:
    displayBoard(HANGMANPICS, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord)
    print 'You have run out of guesses!\nAfter ' + str(len(missedLetters)) + ' missed guesses and ' + str(len(correctLetters)) + ' correct guesses, the word was "' + secretWord + '"'
    gameIsDone = True

if gameIsDone:
    if playAgain():
        missedLetters = ''
        correctLetters = ''
        gameIsDone = False
        secretWord = getRandomWord(words)
    else:
        break
```

In the second function displayBoard, 4 parameters are passed. I understand HANGMANPICS, missedLetters and secretWord, but I don't understand where the argument for correctLetters is defined/substituted.

In layman's term (as I am a newbie), where does it say what correctLetters should do? I have been studying this game for a week now, and so far everything seems Ok, except this one.

Please help.

Comment: The -1 was pretty fast. At least you could have answered my question, rather than just discourage. I am still very new to this whole thing.

Comment: “At least you could have answered my question”? Er, a downvote could mean quite the opposite…

Comment: Well, as I said I am new to the programming world, and I am very committed to learning, but since I am from a non technical background, I am facing a lot of roadblocks. The above maybe a trivial question for most of you, but not for me.

Comment: It is okay to re-read the chapter again and again until you really understand it all. You may just be confused about what kind of value it should hold, in which case debugging the program can show you. Or you can print the value it holds. http://inventwithpython.com/chapter9.html#DisplayingtheBoardtothePlayer

Comment: You're getting downvotes because you essentially said "here's a bunch of code. It's not working. How do I fix it?" without being very specific about what's not working, the expected behavior and the observed behavior. I'm sure that if you identified these aspects and included all and ONLY those, you'd get a better response

Comment: My code is working perfectly. I had a question about one aspect of the code. However, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`correctLetters` is initialized in this line:

`correctLetters = ''`

and appended to inside the `while` loop that contains the bulk of the game logic:

```
if guess in secretWord:
    correctLetters = correctLetters + guess
```

It is used to keep track of correctly guessed letters, and passed to `displayBoard` so that they can be shown on screen.

As an aside, since white space is important in Python code, it's worth formatting your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a quick keyword search for `correctLetters` you can see it is described as a string. In the function `displayBoard` you can see it used on line 78.

```
if secretWord[i] in correctLetters:
            blanks = blanks[:i] + secretWord[i] + blanks[i+1:]
```

It is being used to put in the letter instead of a blank if the user has guessed that letter.

It is described on one of the bullets [here](http://inventwithpython.com/chapter9.html#DisplayingtheBoardtothePlayer)

It's usage is explained [here](http://inventwithpython.com/chapter9.html#DisplayingtheSecretWordwithBlanks)